# Unable to call action from view page in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a button inside for each loop,if i click the button display the popup using java script.Pop up view also in java script.In popup window another button is there"Subscribe button".If i click subscribe need to go home controller action method.
Here i am using `form action="@Url.Action("Superoffer")" method="POST"`for calling the action but not working.
The Below all code in View page.
**Button**

```
<button class="plan-button demo" >Choose Plan</button>
```

## Form to call action

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Superoffer")" method="POST">
            <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
            <script>
                var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                    key: "",
                    image: "https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png",
                    name: "Abacus",
                    description: "Pro Subscription Package",
                    panelLabel: "Subscribe",
                    allowRememberMe: false
                });
                var el = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
                for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                    el[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                        handler.open();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
                //document.getElementsByClassName("plan-button").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                //    handler.open();
                //    e.preventDefault();
                //});
            </script>

            <div class="spelled-out">ABACUS</div>

</form>
```

Comment: What do you want to do when user submitting "subscribe" form? Provide details what kind of action doesn't work during form submit there.

Comment: After Clicking Subscribe button need to go superoffer action method.Pop up form opening button also working but failed to call the action after click subscribe

Comment: i think you have to define controller name in @url.action else you may need to do related changes in your route.config file

Comment: @IamMohan Right click view page source. Check your form's `action` attribute. It should look like `action='Home/Superoffer'`. Adding controller name to `@Url.action("Home","SuperOffer")` should resolve your issue.